# Permutations with the same sum

Tags: inequality, permutations

**Note:** Rearrangement Inequality is

$$x_ny_1 + \ldots + x_1y_n \leq x_{\sigma(1)}y_1+ \ldots + x_{\sigma(n)}y_n \leq x_1y_1+\ldots + x_ny_n$$

for every choice of real numbers

$$x_1 \leq \ldots \leq x_n$$ and

$$y_1 \leq \ldots \leq y_n$$

and every permutation $x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}$ of $x_1, \ldots , x_n$.

I need to find all permutations which gives the same sum.

For example, for $$\sigma =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  3&  4&  5& 6\\ 
 2&  5&  6&  3&  4& 1
\end{pmatrix}, \omega =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  3&  4&  5& 6\\ 
 6&  3&  4&  1&  2& 5
\end{pmatrix}, \theta =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  3&  4&  5& 6\\ 
 6&  1&  4&  5&  2& 3
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
The sum is $ \sum_{i=1}^{6} i\cdot \sigma(i)= \sum_{i=1}^{6} i\cdot \theta(i)= \sum_{i=1}^{6} i\cdot \omega(i)=68$.

**Question:** Find the condition for permutations $\sigma, \theta$ for which  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot \sigma(i)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot \theta(i)$.

Comment: I am no expert of this topic, but this seems related to the inversion statistics of permutations, see [*this*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220191/weighted-permutation-sum), [*this*](https://oeis.org/A135298), [*this*](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000055/) and [*this*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1995.pdf).